# Check substring in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, include, indexof

when I have the word SAC and Assessoria inside the array it just returns the first if, what is wrong with this logic?

If the array (skills) has the substring SAC I want to make a setState with response.data.SAC which is also an array

If the array (skills) has the substring Assessoria I want to make a setState with response.data.AC which is also an array

if you have both substrings SAC and Assessoria, I want to make a setState with response.data.SAC and response.data.AC, they are both arrays

code below:

```
getDataTab() {
    const URL = `${Utils.ngrok_service}`;

    const skills = this.props.manager.workerClient.attributes.routing.skills;

    axios.post(URL).then((response) => {

      skills.map((item, index) => {

        if (item.includes('SAC')) {
          console.log('SAC EXISTE');
          this.setState({ options: response.data.SAC });
        } else if (item.includes('Assessoria')) {
          console.log('AC EXISTE');
          this.setState({ options: response.data.AC });
        } else if (item.includes('SAC') && item.includes('Assessoria')) {
          console.log('ambos EXISTE');
          this.setState({
            options: [...response.data.SAC, ...response.data.AC],
          });
        } else {
          console.log('nada EXISTE');
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @hev1 
I edited my question please read

Comment: You check for one thing that is generic. You than check for something more specific. Of When you have SAC  and Assessoria, it is not going to get there because the SAC check will be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the state once on each iteration, instead of iterating over the whole array first to check the conditions. The order of your conditional checks is also incorrect.

```
let hasSAC = false, hasAssessoria = false;
skills.forEach(item=>{
    hasSAC = hasSAC || item.includes("SAC");
    hasAssessoria = hasAssessoria || item.includes("Assessoria");
});
if(hasSAC && hasAssessoria){
     console.log('ambos EXISTE');
     this.setState({
        options: [...response.data.SAC, ...response.data.AC],
     });
} else if(hasSAC){
     console.log('SAC EXISTE');
     this.setState({ options: response.data.SAC });
} else if(hasAssessoria){
    console.log('AC EXISTE');
    this.setState({ options: response.data.AC });
} else {
    console.log('nada EXISTE');
}
```

Comment: @PauloRodrigues Glad to help.